# Creating unique threads within a Thread Group

Tags: java, jmeter

I am in the process of testing the log-in functionality of a website.  Ideally I wish to create a Thread Group that consists of a 100 threads.  Each one of these threads would represent a unique user attempting to log-in to the website and perform some basic activities.

I have been unsuccessful in devising a way for making the threads created in a thread group to represent a unique user.  The problem is each time a thread is created it is created as a 'clone' of the first thread created from the Thread Group.  As a result, I cannot configure thread 2 to have a different username/pw than thread 1 because when thread 2 is created JMeter does not know that it is thread 2.

I think that the solution lies in creating some JMETER properties (instead of variables) that maintains its state between threads of the Thread Group.  However, I do not know how to go about implementing this.

any tips or ideas?

thanks.

Comment: can we see some code? don't leave us in the dark [:(](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_oWDv0yWcZ6Q/S_ybzrWeigI/AAAAAAAAAFI/jMGN_e4_v_0/s1600/Jack_crying.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way: use [CSV Data Set](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) for login/password specification

Second way: use ${__threadNum} function to get number of thread in your samplers and use user1, user2, user3 etc. as usernames if applicable

Comment: Thank you very much Andrey for the help.  Using the ${__threadNum} function gave me exactly what I wanted.